# Ошибка при поиске символа в массиве

Tags: java

Хочу в массиве найти максимально длинное слово. Но ошибка строке:

```
if (array[i] > max)
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно исправить?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Введите размер массива:");
int size = scanner.nextInt();
String[] array = new String[size];
String max = array[0];
System.out.println("Введите элементы массива:");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = scanner.next();
}
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > max)
        max = array[i];
}
System.out.println("Результат: " + max);
```

Answer (score 2):

измерять нужно длину строки

```
if (array[i].length() > max.length())
```

Comment: Если так if (array[i].length() > max.length()) то ошибка NPE

Answer (score 1):

(array[i].length() > max), где max - длинна строки

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "мяч рама самолет";
String[] words = a.split(" ");
Arrays.sort(words);
System.out.println(words.get(words.length - 1));
```

Как вариант.. Режем строку в слова, получаем массив слов, сортируем его и берем последний